# Why code in a class was executed when only importing it?

Tags: python, class, parameters, default

Python module (a_module.py):

```
class A:

    def __init__(self):
        self.parameter = 'ABC'
        print('class A is executed')

class B:

    def __init__(self, p:str = A().parameter):
        print('class B is executed')

class C:

    def __init__(self):
        c =A().parameter
        print('class C is executed')
```

test.py:

```
import a_module
```

When I run test.py class A is executed:

```
$ python test.py
class A is executed
```

Is it expected? Any documentation mentions this behavior?

Comment: The init function on B calls A.  Default parameters are called at function def time so, when B is defined, it's init function is defined, and this goes ahead and instantiates the default parameter

Comment: "I've seen the following thread which is slightly different:" It is a combination of that, and the fact that the *default value for the parameter* needs to be created ahead of time. See the linked duplicate for details.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel This has nothing to do with the default value being mutable (it isn't, it's a string).

Comment: @Barmar it's not the same symptom, but it's the same disease.  See my comment.

Comment: @Barmar I know that. But the canonical question isn't really about the mutability; it's about the fact that an object is created ahead of time and reused (which is why the mutability matters).

Comment: It's because the _definition_ of `B.__init__` calls `A()`, and _definitions_ are executed at import.  If the call to `A()` were _inside_ `B.__init__`, this wouldn't happen.

Comment: [this answer to the duped question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11416002/2886575) should help you to solve this issue.